# Convert String to Array of Specific Format

Tags: matlab

I have a string of format

`"'Year'-'Month'-'Day'T'Hour':'Minute':'Second'Z"` for example `'2020-11-26T16:56:09.676Z'`

(Note the milliseconds are considered part of the second)

I would like to convert it to the format:

```
t1 = 1x6

2020 11 26 16 56 09.676
```

Or in other words a 1x6 array.

Note: This is to be completed using MatLab.

Answer (score 1):

You can

1. Use [`regexp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) with the `'match'` input flag to detect the numbers as one or more digits (`\d+`) optionally followed by a decimal point (`\.?`) and then zero or more digits (`\d*`). This will give a cell array of strings.
2. Apply [`str2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) to convert the strings to numbers. This will give a numeric row vector.

```
s = '2020-11-26T16:56:09.676Z';
result = str2double(regexp(s, '\d+\.?\d*', 'match'));
```